# How to call URL in flutter https://key:secret@payment.api/payments/transactionid/update

Tags: dart, flutter

How to call url like this https://key:secret@payment.api/payments/transactionid/update, I've called with http.get(Uri.parse"https://key:secret@payment.api/payments/transactionid/update");
but got the following error.

E/flutter ( 8892): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 8892): FormatException: Invalid port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `key:secret` part of the URL is the authentication credentials, which have to be handled differently in Dart. The Dart http client supports authentication, but as this results in a second round trip of the server, you can add the authentication header yourself. Assuming that your server is expecting `Basic` authentication, try...

```
void update() async {
  String username = 'key';
  String password = 'secret';

  http.Response r = await http.get(
    'https://payment.api/payments/transactionid/update',
    headers: {'authorization': basicAuthorizationHeader(username, password)},
  );
  print(r.statusCode);
  print(r.body);
}

String basicAuthorizationHeader(String username, String password) {
  return 'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call API with below code and let me know:

```
const _apiUrl = "http://example.com/api";
Future getProductDetail(product_id) async {

  String apiUrl = '$_apiUrl/app/get-product?id=$product_id';
  http.Response response = await http.get(apiUrl,headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
  });
  print("Result: ${response.body}");
  return json.decode(response.body);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replay, this snippet you've sent is not worked for this url structure. by adding port it is worked.  https://key:secret@payment.api:443/payments/transactionid/update

Comment: Please check this if helpful

Comment: var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url).send();